# Sending email via django on windows

Tags: python, django, email, outlook, smtp

Ugh, I have tried as many ways is I have been able to find online thus far, but to no avail. My primary objective is to send email from a django based web application on a private LAN. I don't care how it happens...smtp or win32com and outlook...anything, as long is it works.

Using django default settings and this code in a django shell:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('subject','message','myemail@email.com',['myemail@email.com'])
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Python27_32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py", line 50, in send_mail
        connection=connection).send()
    File "C:\Python27_32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 274, in send
        return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
    File "C:\Python27_32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 87, in send_messages
        new_conn_created = self.open()
    File "C:\Python27_32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 48, in open
        local_hostname=DNS_NAME.get_fqdn())
    File "C:\Python27_32\lib\smtplib.py", line 250, in __init__
        (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
    File "C:\Python27_32\lib\smtplib.py", line 311, in connect
        (code, msg) = self.getreply()
    File "C:\Python27_32\lib\smtplib.py", line 359, in getreply
        + str(e))
SMTPServerDisconected: Connection unexpectedly closed: [Errno 10057] A request to send or 
receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a 
datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

After digging into the code, I inserted a print statement in smtplib showing the address as `('localhost', 25)`. So I don't know why it says no address was supplied. That's when I discovered `django-smtp-ssl.py` and after installing added the following to my settings:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True #also tried 1
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_smtp_ssl.SSLEmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@email.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
```

Then executing the same code, I now get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Python27_32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py", line 50, in send_mail
        connection=connection).send()
    File "C:\Python27_32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 274, in send
        return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
    File "C:\Python27_32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 87, in send_messages
        new_conn_created = self.open()
    File "C:\Python27_32\lib\site-packages\django_smtp_ssl.py", line 12, in open
        local_hostname=DNS_NAME.getfqdn())
    File "C:\Python27_32\lib\smtplib.py", line 777, in __init__
        SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout)
    File "C:\Python27_32\lib\smtplib.py", line 250, in __init__
        (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
    File "C:\Python27_32\lib\smtplib.py", line 311, in connect
        (code, msg) = self.getreply()
    File "C:\Python27_32\lib\smtplib.py", line 355, in getreply
        line = self.file.readline()
    File "C:\Python27_32\lib\smtplib.py", line 186, in readline
        chr = self.sslobj.read(1)
    File "C:\Python27_32\lib\ssl.py", line 160, in read
        return self._sslobj.read(len)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I have additionally tried sending mail via Outlook and `win32com` in a production environment using Apache. I have received a couple different exceptions trying this, such as: `'Server execution failed` and `'Call was rejected by callee'`. Although it works in a django shell (of course).

Has anyone seen these any of these errors and found resolution? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

And it's the workaround, nothing short of shoddy, but it'll get the job done until a better solution presents itself.

First I created a [custom command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/) that can be called from `manage.py` as it is not executed from the Apache server (which further tells me that the system does not recognize Apache as a valid user for automatic email generation, certainly there's a way to tell the system "it's okay").

Following that, I created a task in Windows Task Scheduler to run every 30 min (which will suffice for the objective). Action:

```
Start a program  C:\python27_32\python.exe C:\www\myproject\manage.py send_email
```

myapp/management/commands/send_email.py

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from myapp.util.gen_email import AutoEmail #custom code to generate email via win32com
from myapp.models import MyModel

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Command, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        items = MyModel.objects.filter(status__in=['status_a','status_b'])
        if items:
            self.send_proc_email()

    def send_proc_email(self):
        subject = 'There are new items to process'
        to = 'someemail@email.com'
        message = ''
        email = AutoEmail(subject, message, to)

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Far from optimal, I know, but hey if it works...